# Ubuntu 20.04 on ThinkPad T14 gen 1 amd

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad

I install the Ubuntu 20.04 on ThinkPad T14 gen 1 amd version, I met bellow issues:

1. the HDMI output seems not function, so I can't share my screen during presentation;
2. I use a vpn software electron-ssr, not able to start in Ubuntu 20.04;
3. some application is not available since the qt4 is removed.

Any suggestion?

I can see there is a certification for Ubuntu 18.04 and ThinkPad T14 gen1 Intel version, where can I get the image and is it also available for AMD version?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please see the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions in this site. In particular, ask one question at a time. Before asking each question please search the site in case the same question has been answered before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue with hdmi port. When I plug a screen on it, there is nothing. were you able to get a screen to work on the hdmi port?

EDIT: Ok i've found the solution, you have to update the kernel, ubuntu 20.04 comes with old kernel, so update it to 5.8 :
https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/

Comment: I also fix HDMI issue by update the kernel.

Answer (score -1):

Your certification is here [certification.ubuntu.com](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202005-27918)
Perhaps edit yoiur question and ask the 3 questions separately so you have a better chance of some answers.

Comment: The certification is only valid for the Intel, not the AMD variant.

Comment: @FlorianSchlag [This](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202006-27980) is the updated certification for the AMD version ?

Comment: @fixxxer yes, that's the new certification for the AMD version of T14.