# HDMI not working on Lenovo Thinkpad T14 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lenovo, hdmi, thinkpad

After trying out the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078539/hdmi-port-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04), which did not solve my issue, I decided to ask the question:

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Thinkpad T14, but I can not connect to an external monitor via HDMI cable. I tried it with 2 different displays so the source of the problem should be on the laptop side.

Can someone help me out solving it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should [work](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202005-27918)

Comment: Works neither on Fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation and also not on Fresh KUbuntu 20.04. The laptop is freshly bought. Not only HDMI, also screen brightness adjustment is also not working

Comment: Looking at the specs it seems to be a problem with the integrated AMD GPU. AMD is not very well supported by Linux, but someone solved it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265199/ubuntu-20-04-on-thinkpad-t14-gen-1-amd)

Comment: @kanehekili unfortunately I have seen this question that you have mentioned just now. It could have saved me a day and serious effort. I had solved it exactly like it by myself by simply updating to a newer kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by updating to a new kernel. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS comes with a Kernel 5.4.0 which was problematic both for HDMI and also screen brightness adjustment in my case.

Solution: I simply updated to a newer Kernel, (5.9.0 in my case) and those issues were solved without any additional step required. I hope this helps many others who are disappointed at the moment and reading this page.

Comment: Is your Thinkpad T14 AMD or Intel version? Do you have Secure Boot configured?
My setup is AMD + Secure Boot (which was recommended to me via Ubuntu installer) and I quite struggle to install newest kernels (5.8/5.9) as they're naturally unsigned packages.

Answer (score 0):

for me on Lenovo Thinkpad E15

I did upgrade to the Linux kernel 5.0 and linux-firmware to the latest version by using the following commands:

## sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1 linux-firmware

## sudo reboot

the problem was solved.